# Create Gitlab CI job through for loop

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have 100 folders in my repo.
I will need to create one job for each folder under one stage.

How can I create multiple job through a for loop in gitlab-ci.yml to be displayed under one stage?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

There is no "loop" construct in YAML or GitLab CI definitions, but there's a few ways you might approach this problem. I'll describe 3 possible approaches in order of practicality.

### 1. Dynamic child pipelines

You can use a job to create a [dynamic child pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines) yaml programmatically. This is probably the approach with the lowest maintenance and fewest restrictions, if you're willing to script the child pipeline creation, as documented in the link.

```yaml
generate-config:
  script:
    # use a script to generate a YAML containing the 100 jobs you want
    - generate-ci-config > generated-config.yml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - generated-config.yml

child-pipeline:
  needs: [generate-config]
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: generated-config.yml
        job: generate-config
```

You would need to implement the script, but in Python it might look something like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

JOB_TEMPLATE = """\
"{name}_job":
  variables:
    DIRNAME: "{name}"
  script:
    - make "$DIRNAME"

"""

generated_yaml = ''

for name in os.path.listdir():
    if name.startswith('.') or not os.path.isdir(name):
        continue  # or use whatever condition makes sense for you
    job_definition = JOB_TEMPLATE.format(name=name)
    generated_yaml += job_definition

print(generated_yaml)
```

### 2. Wildstar includes

With this approach, you would create a yaml file in in each directory, for example like `folder1/job.yml`, `folder2/job.yml`, etc. and commit this to the repo. Each file should contain a uniquely named job definition. Then in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` use an [include with wildstar glob](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-includelocal-with-wildcard-file-paths) to include all the yaml files.

```
include:
  - local: "*/job.yml"
```

This can be approached similar to the dynamic child pipeline approach discussed above, except perhaps you might script the generation of the `*/job.yml` files programmatically and commit them instead. This would also avoid the child pipeline view, if you find that desirable.

Note that there is a default limit of 150 includes -- self-managed instances [can increase this limit](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/settings/continuous_integration.html#maximum-includes). There are also [size limits](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/instance_limits.html#maximum-size-and-depth-of-cicd-configuration-yaml-files), but this is unlikely to be an issue.

### 3. Parallel Matrix

Use [`parallel:matrix:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallelmatrix) to create 100 jobs from a single definition. However, note that you'll have to write each of the 100 directory names into the YAML in this approach. This is probably the least flexible approach.

Note: there is a limit of 200 permutations allowed with this method.

```yaml
myjob:
  script: # or whatever
    - make $DIRECTORY_NAME
  parallel:
    matrix:
      # edit to include all your directories...
      - DIRECTORY_NAME: [folder1, folder2, folder3, etc]
```

Comment: Thank you, solution 1 works wonder.
Personally felt that solution 3 can be great too, but unfortunate that parallel do not accept variables input